# Is it possible to write IRQ replacing in kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm new to linux kernel programming, and for quite a long time I'm trying to write module, which should do the folowing: replace default irq handler with my own and restore default one after that, work with IDT (try to save idt replace it with my own one, even without changing it's content).
I've spent a lot of time trying to do this, but did'n managed to do anything. So I wonder if it is possible at all or maybe new versions of kernel firbids doing things like these?

Comment: I think it is an extremely bad idea. A module should not hurt the overall architecture of the Linux kernel.

Comment: Well, if it was a real project, I would never use things like that. But now my task is to learn how irq's and etc. work and to manipulate them as I described earlier.

Comment: Perhaps Linux is not the best platform for such experimentation...

Comment: I think that if what you want is playing with IRQs you'd better write a small [OS](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) and play with the GDT and IDT. I think it'll be easier, more enjoyable than hacking the linux kernel. This way you will be able to play with hardware interrupts and software interrupts.

Comment: How _Interrupts_ work and are used by device drivers in an Operating system like Linux and how _IRQs_ and/or _the x86 architecture hardware interrupt mechanism_ is used by an operating system are two very different things. To experiment with the latter, you're going to the level of _writing your own OS_ (or, if you do it in the context of an existing OS like Linux, _rewriting_ parts of the "guts" of the OS). In that context, the answer to your question is "yes". Note you asked _is it possible ..._ not _how do I ..._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've spent a lot of time on this, so the answer is no. Do not try to. You actually can replace handler, but you can't restore it. I've found a possibility to restore it, but required structures and functions are Translate not available (meaning they cant be used, after kernel is already assembled).